# Loss of inferred type when implementing pipe parameters as an array

Tags: typescript, generics, pipeline, typescript-generics, chaining

I am trying to type a pipe function where the values in the pipe are passed as array, but I have an issue that all types except the first and last are inferred as "unknown".

Here is an initial example where the pipe values are separate parameters and all inferred types are as expected (derived from the pipe method in RxJS):

```
    type UnaryFunction<P, R> = (singleParameter:P)=>R
        
    declare function p(): null;
    declare function p<A>(op1: UnaryFunction<null, A>): A;
    declare function p<A,B>(op1: UnaryFunction<null, A>, op2: UnaryFunction<A, B>): B;
    declare function p<A,B,C>(op1: UnaryFunction<null, A>, op2: UnaryFunction<A, B>, op3: UnaryFunction<B, C>): C;
     
    p();
    p(()=>1);
    p(()=>1, x=>'a');
    p(()=>1, x=>'a', xIsString=>true);  // hover over "xIsString" to see that the type is correctly "string"
```

Here is the same example converted so that the parameters are passed in an array.  However, the inferred type B in the last example is now "unknown".

```
declare function q(elements: []): null;
declare function q<A>(elements: [UnaryFunction<null, A>]): A;
declare function q<A,B>(elements: [UnaryFunction<null, A>, UnaryFunction<A, B>]): B;
declare function q<A,B,C>(elements: [UnaryFunction<null, A>, UnaryFunction<A, B>, UnaryFunction<B, C>]): C;
 
q([]);
q([ ()=>1 ]);
q([ ()=>1, x=>'a']);
q([ ()=>1, x=>'a', xIsUnknown=>true]); // hover over "xIsUnknown" to see that the type is "unknown"
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgQwE4gGIFc4GNgEsD2cAPAAoA0UASgHxQC8UAFAM65wDmANhCcggLYRgEJAC4SASjrVKAWABQCgPRKoAQSgAiMLkiaoAdwAWI6BARYjUAGaYcBOFFzMoCKMwhg+wqF6QCEYSRDfCQAaxcEFwgAD0gcCAATUShgEygkIXQkR1BIJxc2axFMxKgsUMycThAKBDgytOg-AKDmZVVgfFT022w8QkjMpzhipFLyyohqkBskfH4e6EzgbNzwaHxrJd9MgDcCdBc++0IAOgVE6c5kaBOBxzBGCRS4dE5OAG5L69ubOweviIamojHwYAAjCl4Mg0ACHEQ3h8KCCXupvvIrlgbsN7g4gWoyAAhUHgqGwRAoDD9BFIzgo6gUcEAJmhlLhNMIwIoJLRRIxWJxd3hhAJxLIAGFSZC2bDqadiHSGUywKyKXKRcRCVASSqAMyyqmaohEihStESjFQBRPCQYp7PaQQu02xiO6gQigxaQAcgQPpd8gdUg9Xt9-q9AElmABlYBINjsaTx9AQO1QKAqKBGfB7ERQXP5zQxaNxhMcfRddwQaBpQI7PLQZyTcbTYA1LTMeOJzQKDpQADqJly6W0ugg+mbsTAmWYHjKUVcjmQ-lmTRHd1wSC7S7KNx3jaGTdGJSSLaq7dqUAARuhgDtZ-e-ppMGE4PgDHBe5jfrjNVAAEdGAgbhBDgYBmBSABtABdNE6QFX9hU5RwAOBUEQIgMCIOgmEjRQxF3npdRqDglI1EQ7E-jxUU0MJElgNAiBwMgqAoLwjkFUI5ESIoDj5QebkdVIvlKKFf4UMA7lTSlRisOYnC2P440lV49V8K47VdXUzjBNNKApTIgyrQUIDYMDMymBDCEoDgjFLPdT0oG9ag-R9OzTMYKCrKdMNXIjZzo3gN8PzgZMkFTOzM1UHM82CQtgmLIK4BCz9K26DxayMesmlSDYCi0V93zShQgA)

Should this solution work, or is there another approach to solving it?

Comment: Please update your playground link, there is only one line

Comment: From the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65431379/type-property-relying-on-return-type-of-another-property): it's a design limitation of TS, see [microsoft/TypeScript#38872](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872). The compiler doesn't do a good job with both contextual and generic type parameter inference for a single function parameter.  You'll have to either manually specify the type parameters, or manually annotate callback parameters (as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/QmbXPw)).