# How to infer generic array items based on the item context

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```js
interface PayloadMap {
  a: { first: string };
  b: { second: string };
  c: { third: string };
  d: { fourth: string };
}

type Keys = keyof PayloadMap;

interface Foo<T extends Keys> {
  key: [T, ...T[]];
  fn(payload: PayloadMap[T]): void;
}

function doSomethingWithListOfFooObjects<T extends Foo<Keys>>(values: [T, ...T[]]): void {}

doSomethingWithListOfFooObjects([
  {
    key: ['a'],
    fn(payload) { // <-- paylod should be inferred to PayloadMap['a'], but it as inferred to PayloadMap['a' | 'b' | 'd']
      // ...
    }
  },
  {
    key: ['b', 'd'],
    fn(payload) { // <-- paylod should be inferred to PayloadMap['b' | 'd'], but it as inferred to PayloadMap['a' | 'b' | 'd']
      // ...
    }
  }
])
```

Is there any way how to infer the type of `payload` correctly according to the information provided by its context?
I already tried to use `const` assertions as well (`key: ['a'] as const`), but it doesn’t make a difference.

Comment: This is going to end up being another problem with the inability of the compiler to infer both generic type parameters and contextual callback parameter types in a single object, as raised in [microsoft/TypeScript#38872](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872); see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65431379/type-property-relying-on-return-type-of-another-property). Would you be interested in a refactoring workaround or do you just want a "sorry this probably won't work" answer?

Comment: I would be happy to see an alternative approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we use your original definition of `doSomethingWithListOfFooObjects`:

```
function doSomethingWithListOfFooObjects<T extends Foo<Keys>>(
  values: [T, ...T[]]): void { }
```

and somehow solve the inference problem, you will hit another problem immediately:

```
declare const fooBD: Foo<"b" | "d">
doSomethingWithListOfFooObjects([fooA, fooBD]); // error!
// Argument of type '[Foo<"a">, Foo<"b" | "d">]' is not assignable 
// to parameter of type '[Foo<"a">, ...Foo<"a">[]]
```

The issue is that when you write `[T, ...T[]]`, you are essentially enforcing that `T` should be the same for each element of `values`, or at least giving the compiler a strong hint to that effect.  There are only some situations in which the compiler will synthesize a union for an inferred type parameter, and depending on how you try to use your existing definition you can easily run afoul of those rules.

To avoid this, I would suggest refactoring `doSomethingWithListOfFooObjects` to the following form:

```
function doSomethingWithListOfFooObjects<
  L extends [Foo<Keys>, ...Foo<Keys>[]]
>(values: L): void { }
```

which allows `L` to be a tuple type where each element type differs from every other type.

---

Please note that the only reason you can use `Foo<Keys>` at all to represent a supertype of something like `Foo<"a">` or `Foo<"b" | "d">` is that method parameters like `fn()`'s `payload` parameter are type checked [*bivariantly*](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant), and so `Foo<"a">` is considered assignable to `Foo<Keys>`.  If you were to slightly change the definition of `Foo` (with [`--strictFunctionTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) enabled) to the following, this would break:

```
interface FooRefactor<K extends Keys> {
  key: [K, ...K[]];
  fn: (payload: PayloadMap[K]) => void; // change from method syntax fo function syntax
}
declare const fooRefactorA: FooRefactor<"a">
const fooRefactorKeys: FooRefactor<Keys> = fooRefactorA; // error!
```

It is possible to change `doSomethingWithListOfFooObjects` to a version that would work with `FooRefactor` instead of `Foo`, but I'm not going to worry about that here.

---

Unfortunately, with all that out of the way, **we still have the problem**:

```
doSomethingWithListOfFooObjects([
  { key: ["a"], fn(payload) { console.log(payload.first) } }, // error!
  { key: ["b", "d"], fn(payload) { } }
]);
```

The `payload` types are not [contextually typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) properly.  You are asking the compiler to infer *both* the type parameter `L` (or `T`) *and* to contextually infer the type of the `payload` parameters for each object's `fn()` method.  This doesn't seem to be possible when the multiple inferences need to happen for the same object, and is considered a design limitation of TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#38872](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872) for more information.

---

So we will need a workaround.  It's always possible for you to give up and either manually specify `L` or manually annotate the type of `payload`, but assuming you'd like to avoid that, I'd suggest a helper function:

```
const foo = <K extends Keys>(
  key: [K, ...K[]],
  fn: (payload: PayloadMap[K]) => void
): Foo<K> => ({ key, fn });
```

Here instead of writing `{key: [...], fn(payload){...}}` which requires inference of a single object, you write `foo([...], function(payload){...})`, which produces the same result, but allows the compiler to infer `K` in the first argument and the contextual type of `payload` in the second argument:

```
doSomethingWithListOfFooObjects([
  foo(["a"], function (payload) { console.log(payload.first) }),
  foo(["b", "d"], function (payload) {
    // payload: {  second: string; } | { fourth: string; }
  })
])
```

That works as desired now.  Is it perfect?  Not at all.  But unless some change happens in TypeScript to deal with the issue in microsoft/TypeScript#38872, I don't know of a perfect solution.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#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-QFQACElGDOygPEsWPAMLCrncyAA5FVOcdTvVM-qjSazcVWqnkCSfjh1XBWKw4dbRFgUJHvmA-n0oHB7dBE1o3Ch05mTsUxU0B6cpc4QWCIVCQMh8GjMdjdI6CdpiWSKWkqbSIQyRISWfl8L4M-cbkPGiOz49iuOeXysAKhYTJsgZnN5c54tB4EgOWkACUIF-FsoEyQ82WPZBzzKGgKmqOpLwaFp2k6GAQAYXp+gIBghkiIhSDGcZ-FKd95k+b4EG0OAVBQGBAQxZB7W0HA5VYDBwDgHJtiYKdIWhdjOJySgFWWVZ1jkS5AOAxBQL2f8cCAkCgXSLMzjVDUlNkoEbl1LSIRUmCXmk5SoDeCiQyBCNFgXZi8VXddXU3HBt09b0REkeDhSzVo-R6PphgIYjJAuHAGwaXAeCwwL8AaZg2DAYj+AEepg2gUMIxoTzvGqQ59XqU1Dl8rpovw4KBAEShAwnDSrn8ZBwNyI9Chvbpyhy4VEPFFDfJEdDMIC-DcOwgiSCIki31lShX05DxnlKbpsowPyBHGWJ5ztJd7OdDd3R3el3JoK5vR8v0+JnZBSoGcrQvCyKroIOKWHYJLxlqPq0hO-KCyKs7wX42cHvwYKRBoYNBoGTQpBkOR9C4Xh3mS41zCsGxtDsBHKpofhxiq8YgA)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and also the reference to the typescript issue tracker (I haven’t found this after searching for a couple of hours).
I will go for the helper function workaround for now. That shouldn’t be too hard to implemented, although it is a little bit annoying to know that the function doesn’t do any necessary computation.